# Azure MSAL is redirecting to UnauthenticatedTemplate after Authenticating of my react app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, msal-react, msal

Iam working on a `React` web application which use `Next.js 14` and `App Router`. Iam using `Msal-React` dependency for the same.

I have configured `MSAL` and tried to access with my React app. After authenticating., it is redirecting me to `UnauthenticatedTemplate` which is not expected behaviour.

It is supposed to redirect me to `redirectURI` which is happening., but I see `UnauthenticatedTemplate` on screen.

As per configuration., After Authentication., my app is supposed to stay at `https://myapp.com/dashboard` page.

I see URL redirection is happening., but loading `UnauthenticatedTemplate` on screen.

Can you help me with this configuration issue?

Here is my `Msal.ts` configuration:

```js
import {
  PublicClientApplication,
  Configuration,
  LogLevel,
} from "@azure/msal-browser";

console.log(
  "env",
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_REDIRECT_URL
);
const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID || "default-client-id", // Azure AD client id
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}`, // zure AD tenant id
    redirectUri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_REDIRECT_URL, // app redirect URL
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "/", // app logout URL
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // If you are having issues on IE11, you may need to set this to true
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
        }
      },
      logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
    },
  },
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

export default msalInstance;
```

This is my `layout.tsx` which is a `wrapper` to my React App:

```js
"use client";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./globals.css";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { AppStore, makeStore, persistor } from "@/lib/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import msalInstance from "@/lib/Msal";
import {
  AuthenticatedTemplate,
  MsalProvider,
  UnauthenticatedTemplate,
} from "@azure/msal-react";
import Home from "./page";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>();
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={storeRef.current.__persistor}>
            <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
              <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                  <Home />
                </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                <AuthenticatedTemplate>{children}</AuthenticatedTemplate>
              </Box>
            </MsalProvider>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

This is my `login.tsx` code:

```js
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Button, Box } from "@mui/material";
import MyLogo from "@/images/NationgridLogo2";
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

const LoginComp: React.FC = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const handleLoginClick = async () => {
    const loginRequest = {
      scopes: ["openId", "profile", "User.Read"],
    };
    instance
      .loginRedirect(loginRequest)
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  return (
    <Box>
      <Container maxWidth="xs" style={{}}>
        <MyLogo />
        <Box margin="normal">
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            fullWidth
            onClick={handleLoginClick}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default LoginComp;
```

**This is the generated log:**

```html
: @azure/msal-browser@3.10.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:initializeEnd
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-browser@3.10.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:handleRedirectStart
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-browser@3.10.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:loginFailure
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-browser@3.10.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:handleRedirectEnd
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-react@2.0.12 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectStart results in setting inProgress from startup to handleRedirect
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-react@2.0.12 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectStart results in setting inProgress from startup to handleRedirect
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-react@2.0.12 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectEnd results in setting inProgress from handleRedirect to none
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-react@2.0.12 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectEnd results in setting inProgress from handleRedirect to none
```